# Android How to implement ImageSwitcher in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to switch images with animation like fade in and fade out, So how to implement this using ImageSwitcher in Compose, Or is there any better way to achieve this in compose?

Comment: did you find a similar component in compose?

Comment: @RakshitSoni No, there is no such component in compose.

Answer (score 0):

`AnimatedContent` is what you want:

```
var contentState: ContentState by remember { mutableStateOf(ContentState.Foo) }
AnimatedContent(contentState) {
    when (it) {
        ContentState.Foo -> Image1()
        ContentState.Bar -> Image2()
    }
}
```